# Custom ListView not working

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-adapter

I am trying to create a custom ListView, and I think I made my adapter correctly.
I'm quite new to android and don't really understand all the concepts with views, and adapters, etc.

My code is all done in a fragment, and not the main activity. I don't know if this will affect how you pass stuff to and from the list.

I am trying to display information that I got from a JSON formatted string. When I run my app, the list never shows up, I don't know if its because I am passing the wrong view or something like that. It doesn't crash.

**personal_profile_fragment:**

```
public class Personal_Profile_Fragment extends Fragment {

private charAdapter adapter;

ListView list;
ArrayList<charactors> charactorList;

public Personal_Profile_Fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_personal__profile_, container, false);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    String JSON = bundle.getString("JSON");

    parseJson(JSON);

    list = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    charactorList = new ArrayList<charactors>();
    adapter = new charAdapter(getContext(), charactorList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    return v;
}

private void parseJson(String json) {
    try {
        JSONObject chars = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray charArray = chars.getJSONArray("heroes");

        for (int i = 0; i<charArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject realCharacter = charArray.getJSONObject(i);

            charactors charactor = new charactors();
            charactor.setName(realCharacter.getString("name"));
            charactor.setClassType(realCharacter.getString("class"));
            charactor.setLevel(realCharacter.getString("level"));
            charactor.setParagonLevel(realCharacter.getString("paragonLevel"));
            charactor.setHardcore(realCharacter.getString("hardcore"));
            charactor.setSeasonal(realCharacter.getString("seasonal"));

            charactorList.add(charactor);
        }

    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
}

}
```

**personal_profile.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/personalProfileFragment"
tools:context="com.hfad.diablo3assistant.Personal_Profile_Fragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="551dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**row.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/classType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/level"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/classType"
        android:layout_below="@+id/classType"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/paragonLevel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/level"
        android:layout_below="@+id/level"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hardcore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/paragonLevel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/paragonLevel"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seasonal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/hardcore"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hardcore"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**charactors class:**

```
public class charactors {
private String name;
private String classType;
private String level;
private String paragonLevel;
private String hardcore;
private String seasonal;

public charactors() {

}



public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getClassType() {
    return classType;
}

public void setClassType(String classType) {
    this.classType = classType;
}

public String getLevel() {
    return level;
}

public void setLevel(String level) {
    this.level = level;
}

public String getParagonLevel() {
    return paragonLevel;
}

public void setParagonLevel(String paragonLevel) {
    this.paragonLevel = paragonLevel;
}

public String getHardcore() {
    return hardcore;
}

public void setHardcore(String hardcore) {
    this.hardcore = hardcore;
}

public String getSeasonal() {
    return seasonal;
}

public void setSeasonal(String seasonal) {
    this.seasonal = seasonal;
}

}
```

**Charactor adapter:**

```
public class charAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<charactors> {
private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<charactors> charactorsArrayList;

public charAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<charactors> charactorsArrayList) {

    super(context, R.layout.row, charactorsArrayList);

    this.context = context;
    this.charactorsArrayList = charactorsArrayList;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // 1. Create inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // 2. Get rowView from inflater
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

    // 3. Get the two text view from the rowView
    TextView name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView classType = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.classType);
    TextView level = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.level);
    TextView paragonLevel = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.paragonLevel);
    TextView hardcore = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.hardcore);
    TextView seasonal = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.seasonal);

    // 4. Set the text for textView
    name.setText("Name: "+charactorsArrayList.get(position).getName());
    classType.setText("Class: "+charactorsArrayList.get(position).getClassType());
    level.setText("Level: "+charactorsArrayList.get(position).getLevel());
    paragonLevel.setText("Paragon: "+charactorsArrayList.get(position).getParagonLevel());
    hardcore.setText("Hardcore: "+charactorsArrayList.get(position).getHardcore());
    classType.setText("Seasonal: "+charactorsArrayList.get(position).getSeasonal());

    // 5. retrn rowView
    return rowView;
}
}
```

Comment: somewhere in your fragment you will need to fill the "charactorList" `ArrayList` with data and initialize your "adapter" properly. Where is that code?

Comment: That's done in the fragment. In the onCreateView function, I just edited the post with what I had thought should work, but doesnt.

Comment: BenP has provided the solution to your issue. But might I suggest that you capitalize the name of your `Adapter` class to "CharAdapter"--that is java naming convention and "charactors" to "Charactors"

Comment: Ah, yea it was getting a tad confusing looking through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your adapter's `getView()` implementation is *inefficient*, but it looks *functionally correct*. I think the problem is just a simple error in your `onCreateView()`:

> ```
> parseJson(JSON);
> ...
> charactorList = new ArrayList<charactors>();
> adapter = new charAdapter(getContext(), charactorList);
> ```

It looks like you're parsing the JSON string and then immediately throwing out the parsing work by assigning a `new ArrayList` to `charactorList`.

Actually, looking a little deeper, it seems likely that `charactorList` is null when `parseJson()` is running (but the `catch` block is hiding this from you). So you just want to rearrange this code a little bit:

```
charactorList = new ArrayList<charactors>();
parseJson(JSON);
...
adapter = new charAdapter(getContext(), charactorList);
```

Comment: Ah, I just needed to move the charactorList = new ArrayList<charactors>();
 above the parseJson!

Comment: @Tyler by the way, if you are just getting into Android programming, I recommend _not_ spending the time learning `ListView`, and instead putting in the effort to learn `RecyclerView`. It's a little more complicated to put together, but it is the Google-recommended replacement for `ListView` and is both more powerful and more performant. The code you have now is likely to drop frames when quickly scrolling through the list.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know about that, the professor didn't show us RecyclerView, but I have seen it popup when looking around the internet with my various errors. Thanks I'll check it out!

Comment: @Tyler it's not like there's anything inherently evil about `ListView`, so if you're supposed to use it for a class then go ahead and do so. It's just like driving an old car... newer cars have more features and burn less fuel.